# Aggregating a list of dates to start and end date

Tags: postgresql

I have a list of dates and IDs, and I would like to roll them up into periods of consucitutive dates, within each ID.

For a table with the columns "testid" and "pulldate" in a table called "data":

```
| A79 | 2010-06-02 |
| A79 | 2010-06-03 |
| A79 | 2010-06-04 |
| B72 | 2010-04-22 |
| B72 | 2010-06-03 |
| B72 | 2010-06-04 |
| C94 | 2010-04-09 |
| C94 | 2010-04-10 |
| C94 | 2010-04-11 |
| C94 | 2010-04-12 |
| C94 | 2010-04-13 |
| C94 | 2010-04-14 |
| C94 | 2010-06-02 |
| C94 | 2010-06-03 |
| C94 | 2010-06-04 |
```

I want to generate a table with the columns "testid", "group", "start_date", "end_date":

```
| A79 | 1 | 2010-06-02 | 2010-06-04 |
| B72 | 2 | 2010-04-22 | 2010-04-22 |
| B72 | 3 | 2010-06-03 | 2010-06-04 |
| C94 | 4 | 2010-04-09 | 2010-04-14 |
| C94 | 5 | 2010-06-02 | 2010-06-04 |
```

This is the the code I came up with:

```
SELECT t2.testid,
  t2.group,
  MIN(t2.pulldate) AS start_date,
  MAX(t2.pulldate) AS end_date
FROM(SELECT t1.pulldate,
  t1.testid,
  SUM(t1.check) OVER (ORDER BY t1.testid,t1.pulldate) AS group
FROM(SELECT data.pulldate,
  data.testid,
  CASE
  WHEN data.testid=LAG(data.testid,1) 
    OVER (ORDER BY data.testid,data.pulldate)
  AND data.pulldate=date (LAG(data.pulldate,1) 
    OVER (PARTITION BY data.testid 
    ORDER BY data.pulldate)) + integer '1'
  THEN 0
  ELSE 1
  END AS check
FROM data 
ORDER BY data.testid, data.pulldate) AS t1) AS t2
GROUP BY t2.testid,t2.group
ORDER BY t2.group;
```

I used the LAG windowing function to compare each row to the previous, putting a 1 if I need to increment to start a new group, I then do a running sum of that column, and then aggregate to the combinations of "group" and "testid".

Is there a better way to accomplish my goal, or does this operation have a name?

I am using PostgreSQL 8.4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's another approach:

```
WITH TEMP_TAB AS (
SELECT testid, pulldate,
       (pulldate + (row_number || ' days')::interval)::date AS dummydate
 FROM ( SELECT *, row_number() OVER () FROM
    ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY testid,pulldate DESC
    ) AS tab1 
 ) AS tab2 
)
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT testid, min(pulldate) AS mindate, max(pulldate) AS maxdate 
    FROM TEMP_TAB GROUP BY testid,dummydate 
  )  AS tab3 
ORDER BY testid, mindate
```

Warning: this strategy breaks if there are repeated `(testid, pulldate)` pairs. In this case, one should first do a DISTINCT over those fields.

*Explanation*: The intermediate table has a `dummydate`, obtained by adding a number of days equal to the "row number" (in the ordered select); its only meaning is that rows with same `dummydate` are in the same set of consecutive dates. Eg: intermediate results:

```
test=#  SELECT *, row_number() OVER  () FROM
test-#   ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY testid,pulldate DESC) AS tab1;
 testid |  pulldate  | row_number
--------+------------+------------
 A79    | 2010-06-04 |          1
 A79    | 2010-06-03 |          2
 A79    | 2010-06-02 |          3
 B72    | 2010-06-04 |          4
 B72    | 2010-06-03 |          5
 B72    | 2010-04-22 |          6
 C94    | 2010-06-04 |          7
 C94    | 2010-06-03 |          8
 C94    | 2010-06-02 |          9
 C94    | 2010-04-14 |         10
 C94    | 2010-04-13 |         11
 C94    | 2010-04-12 |         12
 C94    | 2010-04-11 |         13
 C94    | 2010-04-10 |         14
 C94    | 2010-04-09 |         15



test=# SELECT
test-#  testid,pulldate,(pulldate + (row_number || 'days')::interval)::date AS dummydate
test-#  FROM ( SELECT *, row_number() OVER  () FROM
test(#   ( SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY testid,pulldate DESC) AS tab1 )
test-#  AS tab2;
 testid |  pulldate  | dummydate
--------+------------+------------
 A79    | 2010-06-04 | 2010-06-05
 A79    | 2010-06-03 | 2010-06-05
 A79    | 2010-06-02 | 2010-06-05
 B72    | 2010-06-04 | 2010-06-08
 B72    | 2010-06-03 | 2010-06-08
 B72    | 2010-04-22 | 2010-04-28
 C94    | 2010-06-04 | 2010-06-11
 C94    | 2010-06-03 | 2010-06-11
 C94    | 2010-06-02 | 2010-06-11
 C94    | 2010-04-14 | 2010-04-24
 C94    | 2010-04-13 | 2010-04-24
 C94    | 2010-04-12 | 2010-04-24
 C94    | 2010-04-11 | 2010-04-24
 C94    | 2010-04-10 | 2010-04-24
 C94    | 2010-04-09 | 2010-04-24
```

Edit: The WITH is not necessary here (but i like it nevertheless), this is the same:

```
SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT testid, min(pulldate) AS mindate, max(pulldate) AS maxdate 
  FROM (
    SELECT
      testid,pulldate,
      (pulldate + (row_number || ' days')::interval)::date AS dummydate
    FROM ( SELECT *, row_number() OVER  () FROM
      ( 
       SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY testid,pulldate DESC) AS tab1 )  
       AS tab2 
    ) as temp_tab
  GROUP BY testid,dummydate 
)  AS tab3
ORDER BY testid, mindate
```

Comment: I believe that the `ORDER BY` is placed in the wrong position of the first intermediate, i.e. it should read: `SELECT *, row_number() OVER (ORDER BY testid,pulldate DESC) FROM data`

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any known name for this technique. I tried writing it myself and came up with something essentially equivalent to yours- differing only in having one less WindowAgg.

```
select testid, group_num as group,
       min(pulldate) as start_date,
       max(pulldate) as end_date
from (select testid,
             pulldate,
             sum(case when projected_pulldate is null or pulldate <> projected_pulldate
                      then 1 else 0 end) over (order by testid, pulldate) as group_num
      from (select testid, pulldate,
                   (lag(pulldate, 1) over (partition by testid order by pulldate)
                   ) + 1 as projected_pulldate
            from data) x
     ) grouped
group by testid, group_num
order by 1, 2
```

This is hardly pretty, and I do wonder if this is simply a case where using plpgsql or similar might be a better fit.

```
create or replace function data_extents()
 returns table(testid char(3), "group" int, start_date date, end_date date)
 language plpgsql
 stable as $$
declare
  rec data%rowtype;
begin
  "group" := 1;
  for rec in select * from data order by testid, pulldate loop
    if testid is null then
      -- first row
      testid := rec.testid;
      start_date := rec.pulldate;
      end_date := rec.pulldate;
    elsif rec.testid <> testid or rec.pulldate <> (end_date + 1) then
      -- discontinuity
      return next;
      testid := rec.testid;
      start_date := rec.pulldate;
      end_date := rec.pulldate;
      "group" := "group" + 1;
    else
      end_date := end_date + 1;
    end if;
  end loop;
  if testid is not null then
    return next;
  end if;
end;
$$;
```

This is hardly pretty either... although it is in principle deriving the output from a single scan without doing several different aggregations, which at least feels better. It takes just the same time on the tiny dataset; larger dataset? I haven't tried it yet tbh.

Since neither of our solutions allow predicates such as "testid = XXX" to be taken into the scan on data (afaict) a function may be the only way to do efficient filtering?